# How can I insert int3 with ptrace in Ubuntu x64?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, x86-64, ptrace

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints/) to achieve the same results with setting breakpoints, the only difference is I'm on x64 system. So, I have this code for "Hello, World!":

```
; The _start symbol must be declared for the linker (ld)
global _start

section    .text
_start:

    ; Prepare arguments for the sys_write system call:
    ;   - rax: system call number (sys_write)
    ;   - rdi: file descriptor (stdout)
    ;   - rsi: pointer to string
    ;   - rdx: string length
    mov    rax, 1
    mov    rdi, 1
    mov    rsi, msg1
    mov    rdx, len1
    syscall

    ; int3 should be here

    mov    rax, 1
    mov    rdi, 1
    mov    rsi, msg2
    mov    rdx, len2
    syscall

    ; Execute sys_exit
    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall

section   .data
    msg1 db    'Hello, ', 0xa
    len1 equ    $ - msg1
    msg2 db    'world!', 0xa
    len2 equ    $ - msg2
```

This code is compiled like this:`nasm -f elf64 hello.s && ld -s -o hello hello.o`:

```
~$ objdump -d hello    

hello:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <.text>:
  4000b0:   48 b8 01 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x1,%rax
  4000b7:   00 00 00 
  4000ba:   48 bf 01 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x1,%rdi
  4000c1:   00 00 00 
  4000c4:   48 be 1c 01 60 00 00    movabs $0x60011c,%rsi
  4000cb:   00 00 00 
  4000ce:   48 ba 08 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x8,%rdx
  4000d5:   00 00 00 
  4000d8:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4000da:   48 b8 01 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x1,%rax
  4000e1:   00 00 00 
  4000e4:   48 bf 01 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x1,%rdi
  4000eb:   00 00 00 
  4000ee:   48 be 24 01 60 00 00    movabs $0x600124,%rsi
  4000f5:   00 00 00 
  4000f8:   48 ba 07 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x7,%rdx
  4000ff:   00 00 00 
  400102:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400104:   48 b8 3c 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x3c,%rax
  40010b:   00 00 00 
  40010e:   48 bf 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x0,%rdi
  400115:   00 00 00 
  400118:   0f 05                   syscall
```

After that, in a C program I'm trying to set a breakpoint, as it's described in the article.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


void procmsg(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    fprintf(stdout, "[%d] ", getpid());
    va_start(ap, format);
    vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void run_target(const char* programname)
{
    procmsg("target started. will run '%s'\n", programname);

    /* Allow tracing of this process */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        return;
    }

    /* Replace this process's image with the given program */
    execl(programname, programname, (char *)NULL);
}

void run_debugger(pid_t child_pid)
{
    int wait_status;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    procmsg("debugger started\n");

    /* Wait for child to stop on its first instruction */
    wait(&wait_status);

    /* Obtain and show child's instruction pointer */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child started. RIP = 0x%08x\n", regs.rip);

    unsigned addr = 0x004000da;
    unsigned data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("Original data at 0x%08x: 0x%08x\n", addr, data);

    /* Write the trap instruction 'int 3' into the address */
    unsigned data_with_trap = (data & 0xFFFFFF00) | 0xCC;
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data_with_trap);

    /* See what's there again... */
    unsigned readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("After trap, data at 0x%08x: 0x%08x\n", addr, readback_data);

    /* Let the child run to the breakpoint and wait for it to
    ** reach it
    */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    wait(&wait_status);
    if (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child got a signal: %s\n", strsignal(WSTOPSIG(wait_status)));
    }
    else {
        perror("wait");
        return;
    }

    /* See where the child is now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child stopped at RIP = 0x%08x\n", regs.rip);

    /* Remove the breakpoint by restoring the previous data
    ** at the target address, and unwind the EIP back by 1 to
    ** let the CPU execute the original instruction that was
    ** there.
    */
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data);
    regs.rip -= 1;
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);

    /* The child can continue running now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    wait(&wait_status);

    if (WIFEXITED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child exited\n");
    }
    else {
        procmsg("Unexpected signal\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a program name as argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child_pid > 0)
        run_debugger(child_pid);
    else {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code also compiles, but leads to a segmentation fault during execution:

```
~$ ./ptrace_test_bp hello                         
[24100] debugger started
[24101] target started. will run 'hello'
[24100] Child started. RIP = 0x004000b0
[24100] Original data at 0x004000da: 0x0001b848
[24100] After trap, data at 0x004000da: 0x0001b8cc
Hello, 
[1]    24100 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./ptrace_test_bp hello
```

What should I do to make it behave properly (stop on breakpoint and resume) on x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C code is segfaulting in `strsignal` because you have forgotten to `#include <string.h>`.

To be precise, it's segfaulting because without prototype the return value of `strsignal` is assumed to be an int (which is 32 bits) when it is in fact a pointer with 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

@Enchantner, Thank to your question. I met with similar problem recently. It inspired me a lot. After fixing the error according @Jester, there is still segment error. So I spent some time digging into it. Finally, I worked it out.

**The `ptrace` word length for peek/poke is 64 bit, not 32, on x86-64 Linux**. But the code is using `unsigned` (32-bit), which will cast to long type, 64-bit, in the [`ptrace(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html#NOTES) call.

For example, a POKETEXT of `0xaabbccdd` will actually write `0x00000000aabbccdd` to memory, assuming it happens to be zero-extended by the caller. Necessarily, it will mess up memory.

So it will work to change the type to `long`, which is 64-bit in the x86-64 System V ABI.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void procmsg(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    fprintf(stdout, "[%d] ", getpid());
    va_start(ap, format);
    vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void run_target(const char* programname)
{
    procmsg("target started. will run '%s'\n", programname);

    /* Allow tracing of this process */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        return;
    }

    /* Replace this process's image with the given program */
    execl(programname, programname, (char *)NULL);
}

void run_debugger(pid_t child_pid)
{
    int wait_status;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    procmsg("debugger started\n");

    /* Wait for child to stop on its first instruction */
    wait(&wait_status);

    /* Obtain and show child's instruction pointer */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child started. RIP = 0x%08x\n", regs.rip);

    long addr = 0x004000cb;//0x004000da;
    long data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("Original data at 0x%08x: 0x%08x\n", addr, data);

    /* Write the trap instruction 'int 3' into the address */
    long data_with_trap = (data & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00) | 0xCC;
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data_with_trap);

    /* See what's there again... */
    long readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("After trap, data at 0x%08x: 0x%08x\n", addr, readback_data);

    /* Let the child run to the breakpoint and wait for it to
    ** reach it
    */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    wait(&wait_status);
    if (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child got a signal: %s\n", strsignal(WSTOPSIG(wait_status)));
    }
    else {
        perror("wait");
        return;
    }

    /* See where the child is now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child stopped at RIP = 0x%08x\n", regs.rip);

    /* Remove the breakpoint by restoring the previous data
    ** at the target address, and unwind the EIP back by 1 to
    ** let the CPU execute the original instruction that was
    ** there.
    */
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data);

/* See what's there again... */
     readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
     procmsg("After restore, data at 0x%08x: 0x%08x\n", addr, readback_data);


    regs.rip -= 1;
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);

    /* The child can continue running now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    wait(&wait_status);
    if (WIFEXITED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child exited\n");
    } else if(WIFSIGNALED(wait_status)) {
    procmsg("signal !!!\n");
    }
    else {
        procmsg("Unexpected signal. %s \n",  strsignal(WSTOPSIG(wait_status)));
    }
 } 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a program name as argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child_pid > 0)
        run_debugger(child_pid);
    else {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In addition, you must modify the `long addr = 0x004000cb;//0x004000da;` according your compiled object file. You see it's different in my Ubuntu system with the guide.

________________divider______________________________

It's my inference above all and  shows indeed that it solve the problem. But I wanna test more to confirm the conclusion. This is my test code.

**the `objdump -d hello2` output**

```
hello2:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <.text>:
  4000b0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4000b5:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4000ba:   48 be f4 00 60 00 00    movabs $0x6000f4,%rsi
  4000c1:   00 00 00 
  4000c4:   ba 08 00 00 00          mov    $0x8,%edx
  4000c9:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4000cb:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4000d0:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  4000d5:   48 be fc 00 60 00 00    movabs $0x6000fc,%rsi
  4000dc:   00 00 00 
  4000df:   ba 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%edx
  4000e4:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4000e6:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  4000eb:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  4000f0:   0f 05                   syscall
```

**The debugger.c content**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void procmsg(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    fprintf(stdout, "[%d] ", getpid());
    va_start(ap, format);
    vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

void run_target(const char* programname)
{
    procmsg("target started. will run '%s'\n", programname);

    /* Allow tracing of this process */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
        perror("ptrace");
        return;
    }

    /* Replace this process's image with the given program */
    execl(programname, programname, (char *)NULL);
}

void run_debugger(pid_t child_pid)
{
    int wait_status;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    procmsg("debugger started\n");

    /* Wait for child to stop on its first instruction */
    wait(&wait_status);

    /* Obtain and show child's instruction pointer */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child started. RIP = 0x%016x\n", regs.rip);

    long addr = 0x004000cb;//0x004000da;
    unsigned data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("Original data at 0x%016x: 0x%016x\n", addr, data);

    //test
    unsigned data_u = data;
    procmsg("test data_u: 0x%08x\n", data_u);

    /* Write the trap instruction 'int 3' into the address */
    long data_with_trap = (data & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00) | 0xCC;
    ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data_with_trap);

    /* See what's there again... */
    long readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
    procmsg("After trap,set breakpoint, data at 0x%016x: 0x%016x\n", addr, readback_data);

    /* Let the child run to the breakpoint and wait for it to
    ** reach it
    */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    //wait to breakpoint
    wait(&wait_status);
    if (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child got a signal: %s\n", strsignal(WSTOPSIG(wait_status)));
    }
    else {
        perror("wait");
        return;
    }

    /* See where the child is now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
    procmsg("Child stopped at RIP = 0x%016x\n", regs.rip);

    /* Remove the breakpoint by restoring the previous data
    ** at the target address, and unwind the EIP back by 1 to
    ** let the CPU execute the original instruction that was
    ** there.
    */
    int result = ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, (void*)data);
    procmsg("poketext origin  back result %d\n", result);
/* See what's there again... */
     readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
     procmsg("After restore, data at 0x%llx: 0x%llx\n", addr, readback_data);
     int offset = 0;
     for(offset = 1; offset < 25; offset++) {
       readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)(addr+offset), 0);
       procmsg("After restore, data at 0x%llx: 0x%llx\n", addr+offset, readback_data);
     }



    regs.rip -= 1;
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);

    /* The child can continue running now */
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0, 0);

    wait(&wait_status);
    if (WIFEXITED(wait_status)) {
        procmsg("Child exited\n");
    } else if(WIFSIGNALED(wait_status)) {
    procmsg("signal !!!\n");
    }
    else {
        procmsg("Unexpected signal. %s \n",  strsignal(WSTOPSIG(wait_status)));
    }
 } 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a program name as argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child_pid > 0)
        run_debugger(child_pid);
    else {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The `./debugger.o hello2` output**

```
[20832] debugger started
[20833] target started. will run 'hello2'
[20832] Child started. RIP = 0x00000000004000b0
[20832] Original data at 0x00000000004000cb: 0x00000000000001b8
[20832] test data_u: 0x000001b8
[20832] After trap,set breakpoint, data at 0x00000000004000cb: 0x00000000000001cc
Hello, 
[20832] Child got a signal: Trace/breakpoint trap
[20832] Child stopped at RIP = 0x00000000004000cc
[20832] poketext origin  back result 0
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000cb: 0x1b8
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000cc: 0x1
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000cd: 0x0
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000ce: 0x4800000000000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000cf: 0xbe48000000000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d0: 0xfcbe480000000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d1: 0xfcbe4800000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d2: 0x6000fcbe48000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d3: 0x6000fcbe480000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d4: 0x6000fcbe4800
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d5: 0x6000fcbe48
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d6: 0x6000fcbe
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d7: 0x6000fc
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d8: 0xba00000000006000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d9: 0x7ba000000000060
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000da: 0x7ba0000000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000db: 0x7ba00000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000dc: 0x7ba000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000dd: 0xf00000007ba0000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000de: 0x50f00000007ba00
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000df: 0xb8050f00000007ba
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000e0: 0x3cb8050f00000007
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000e1: 0x3cb8050f000000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000e2: 0x3cb8050f0000
[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000e3: 0x3cb8050f00
[20832] Unexpected signal. Segmentation fault
```

Clearly, I just make long to unsigned and write back and print in a loop.

```
......
unsigned data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)addr, 0);
     procmsg("After restore, data at 0x%llx: 0x%llx\n", addr, readback_data);
......
     int offset = 0;
     for(offset = 1; offset < 25; offset++) {
       readback_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void*)(addr+offset), 0);
       procmsg("After restore, data at 0x%llx: 0x%llx\n", addr+offset, readback_data);
     }
.....
```

At last, the output,
`[20832] After restore, data at 0x4000d0: 0xfcbe480000000000`,
shows the instruction in memory
`4000d0:    bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi` 
is written to zero. That causes the `Segmentation fault` as expected.

I am satisfied with the answer by now. ~~

Comment: You say *The word length of instruction is 64 bit, not 32.*  But that doesn't make sense; x86 doesn't *have* fixed-length instruction words.  I think you mean that `ptrace` only allows peek/poke of a `long`, which is 64-bit in the x86-64 System V ABI.  So we're talking about `ptrace` "words", not instruction words.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you make the answer's meaning more accurate and format more beautiful. You did great. Thanks.